Teradata Query Performance
Below query is running for long time with high CPU and IO usage.
Mainly because of last AND condition.
SELECT       
        A.CLMN1
        ,COALESCE(G.oDY_CNT,1)        AS DY_CNT 

FROM
DBNAME.TABLE_A     A

LEFT OUTER JOIN DBNAME.TABLE_H          H
ON A.C_NAME = H.C_NAME

LEFT OUTER JOIN DBNAME.TABLE_I           I   
ON H.CAL_ID = I.CAL_ID
AND I.P_DATE = I.G_DATE

LEFT OUTER JOIN DBNAME.TABLE_K        K  
ON H.CAL_ID = K.CAL_ID
 **AND  (I.FUTURE_DATE + DY_CNT) = K.G_DATE;**

Is there any way to optimize this code?
Thanks in advance.

Not enough information provided to be able to answer; would need index structure, demographics (row counts, join columns unique or highly non-unique, etc.)  What does the alias G refer to? That's not defined in the SQL posted.

Have you checked for recommended statistics, made sure your stats are current, looked at the explain plan?
